# Can't pass and retrieve a parameter inside a URL - GAE, Python, Webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, parameter-passing

I'm stuck with how to retrieve a parameter inside a URL, using GAE, Python, webapp2.

In my main.py file I have a template that constructs a url, something like this:

```
.../products?p=12345
```

In app.yaml I dispatch to products.py with:

```
- url: /products.*
  script: products.application
```

In products.py I have different request handlers, with the URL above, the user is routed to the 1st one:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/products', ProductsPage),
    ('/products-save', SaveProduct),
    ('/products-find', FindProduct),
    ('/products-delete', DeleteProduct),    
    ('/products-search', SearchProducts),
], debug = True)
```

In ProductsPage I do the following:

```
class ProductsPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        p1 = self.request.get('p')
```

But for p1 I just get an empty string.

Any ideas what I'm overlooking?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
p1 = self.request.GET['p']
```

It will return the last occurrence of the `p` being passed to request, at default `request.get()` only returns the first occurrence of `p`, which you may have passed multiple times somewhere from your request.

Or try adding **allow_multiple=True** and it will return *ALL* `p` values being passed, in a list:

```
p1_list = self.request.get('p', allow_multiple=True)
for p1 in p1_list:
    ... check the value inside this list ...
```